# May I alias a symbol in gas?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

Some vector table entry is shared by multiple IRQs in nRF5340. Now I am trying to alias a symbol that represents a vector table entry. I thought the following code works well:

```
.set vector1, 0

.macro reset_vector
vector1
.endm

.set reset_vector, 0x7C0

.ifeq reset_vector - vector1
  .print "reset_vector is an alias of vector1."
.endif
```

However, this code throws the following error message :

```
test.s:7: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
```

I suspect **as** assumes *reset_vector* is undefined when the statement evaluates the expression. Can I alias symbols without a such macro?

Comment: Works here, in the sense that it does not produce an error but it doesn't detect them as the same thing. The macro is different from the symbols it just compares symbol values. What is your assembler version?

Comment: @Jester The version is 2.40.0 (arm-none-eabi).